# Accessing private instance fields of parent class from subclass.. but it works?

Tags: java, super

I have a parent class that has 2 private instance fields but my child class which has no instance fields 'magically' creates 2 instance fields.

```
public class Parent 
{
    private String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    private int age;

    public Parent()
    {
        System.out.println("No-Parameter Constructor");
    }

    public Parent(String firstName, String lastName, int age)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "firstName: " + firstName + " lastName: " + lastName + " age: " + age;
    }

    public String getFN()
    {
        return firstName;
    }
}

public class Student extends Parent 
{

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, int age)
    {
        super(firstName, lastName, age);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Parent p = new Parent("Logi", "Tech", 42);
        Student s = new Student("Logi", "Camera", 21);

        System.out.println(p);
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println(p);
        System.out.println(p.getFN());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
firstName: Logi lastName: Tech age: 42
firstName: LogiStudent lastName: Camera age: 21
firstName: Logi lastName: Tech age: 42
LogiStudent
```

Comment: Yes, that's how inheritance works in Java. I'm unclear what your question is.

Comment: Yes, that magic is called inheritance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not accessing private fields from the Student class. Just look at your code - nowhere in the body of `class Student extends Parent {}` do you refer to those fields in any way.

`class Student extends Parent` is java-ese for: "Let's define this new concept called `Student`. Begin by taking absolutely every single last thing Parent has, and then bolt, *on top of all that*, a few more things".

In other words, if Parent has the field '`age`, then so does `Student`.

accessibility is almost entirely unrelated to this notion; accessibility (`private`) is about which **code** (NOT which instance!!) is allowed to directly interact with things. Given that the `age` field is `private`, whilst every instance of `Student` has that field, the code located in `Student.java` cannot touch that field directly. It is of course free to invoke a method that its superclass does allow access to (such as the `toString` method which is `public`) and then observe as *IT* touches those fields. That's not 'direct access', that's indirect, and that is fine.

Similarly, Student can invoke `getFN()` anywhere it wants, and thus get the first name. It cannot, however, *set* the firstname, unless Parent decides to add a `void setFirstName(String fn) { this.firstName = fn; }` method, of course.